# Kubernetes on CoreOS: Proxy service max out CPU

Tags: docker, coreos, kubernetes

I have installed Kubernetes on CoreOS under VirtualBox Vagrant. I notice that when running, each of the cluster nodes uses 100% CPU and the journalctl shows the same message being repeated:

```
Couldn't read file: /tmp/proxy_config : open /tmp/proxy_config: no such file or directory.
```

This seems to be related to the kubernetes-proxy.service. When I stop the service the CPU usage goes to normal and the logging stops. I read somewhere that the proxy is required on the minions not the master, but I lack understanding of the overall architecture to really know what this means. I guess, my question is: is the proxy required to run Kubernetes on CoreOS and if so, is there some configuration that must happen to make this problem go away?

Comment: Do you have the problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/513) that had numerous reports. It's been [fixed](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/pull/514).

Answer (score 1):

The proxy is required on the nodes(minion).  Here is a link to Google's current design documents to help:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/DESIGN.md